# Extract coefficients from linear combination of kroneckerDelta functions

Tags: matlab, signal-processing

I want to extract coeffients from the sum of kroneckerDelta functions. I have calculated z transform and by taking inverse z transform the results is a linear combination of kroneckerDelta functions. When I use sym2poly, I get the error that it is not a valid function. I have following code

```
clc;
clear all;
syms z
f=[2 4 6 4 2 0];
% f=h0;
c=length(f)
for i=1:c
    z_t(i)=[f(i)*z^-(i-1)];
end
ztransfn=sum(z_t);
invztransfn= iztrans(ztransfn)
```

the result is

```
invztransfn =

4*kroneckerDelta(n - 1, 0) + 6*kroneckerDelta(n - 2, 0) + 4*kroneckerDelta(n - 3, 0) + 2*kroneckerDelta(n - 4, 0) + 2*kroneckerDelta(n, 0)
```

using

```
sym2poly(invztransfn)
```

I get

> Error using sym/sym2poly (line 31) Not a polynomial.
>
> Error in ztransform (line 22) sym2poly(invztransfn)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

How about using  `coeffs` function?
If you type the following text in in Command Window in Matlab:

```
>> coeffs(invztransfn)
```

you will get as a result:

```
[ 2, 2, 4, 6, 4]
```

---

1. [coeffs](http://www.mathworks.com/help/symbolic/coeffs.html)

*I hope this helps. Best regards.*